# Jest error '' TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a function as bellow and when i going to test the function i got the above error.

**function**

```
toggleRecovery = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState(
      {
        recovery: !this.state.recovery
      },
      () => {
        this.props.reset()
      }
    )
  }
```

**test**

```
test('if the recovery state is true should set the state to the false', () => {
      wrapper.setState({ recovery: true })
      //Check if the state is true initially
      expect(wrapper.state().recovery).toBeTruthy()
      //Calling the toggleRecovery()
      wrapper.instance().toggleRecovery()
      expect(wrapper.state().recovery).toBeFalsy()
      expect(props.reset).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

**error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

How can i overcome this error  and what is cause the above error

Comment: you not passing the paramter `e` in here. Suspect even `e` is undefined. Also `e` will need to be an event object, does Jest support event triggering? Add a `console.log(e);` in your event handler just to check. Or `if(e) e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

While calling `toggleRecovery` on instance you can pass the `preventDefault` mock like

```
test('if the recovery state is true should set the state to the false', () => {
      wrapper.setState({ recovery: true })
      //Check if the state is true initially
      expect(wrapper.state().recovery).toBeTruthy()
      //Calling the toggleRecovery()
      wrapper.instance().toggleRecovery({ 
          preventDefault: () => {
      })
      expect(wrapper.state().recovery).toBeFalsy()
      expect(props.reset).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```